# In-built method to deselect child nodes of a node in ExtJs 4 tree panel

Tags: extjs, tree, extjs4

I am using ExtJs tree panel. Is there any in-build method or property which will deselect all the child nodes of a node when you select that node.

So consider the below image, assuming the nodes in yellow back color is already selected. If I select 1.1 now, system should automatically deselect 1.1.2 & if I selected node 1, it should deselect 1.1.2, .1.2.1, 1.2.2.

Please provide your suggestions

[image]

```
Ext.create('Ext.tree.Panel', {
    title: 'Simple Tree',
    renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
    width: 400,
    height: 400,

    store: {
        root: {
            expanded: true,
            children: [{
                text: "1 detention",
                expanded: true,
                "checked": false,
                children: [{
                    text: '1.1 foo',
                    leaf: true,
                    "checked": false
                }, {
                    text: '1.2 bar',
                    leaf: true,
                    "checked": false
                }]
            }, {
                text: "2 homework",
                expanded: true,
                "checked": false,
                children: [{
                    text: "2.1 book report",
                    leaf: true,
                    "checked": false
                }, {
                    text: "2.2 algebra",
                    expanded: true,
                    "checked": false,
                    children: [{
                        text: "2.2.1 buy lottery tickets",
                        leaf: true,
                        "checked": false
                    }, {
                        text: "2.2.2 buy lottery tickets 2",
                        leaf: true,
                        "checked": false
                    }]
                }]
            }, {
                text: "3 buy lottery tickets",
                leaf: true,
                "checked": false
            }]
        }
    },
    useArrows: false,
    rootVisible: false,
    selModel: {
        mode: 'SIMPLE'
    },
    listeners: {
        deselect: function (tree, record) {
            if (record.data.text === '1 detention') {

            }
        },
        select: function (tree, record) {
            var parentNode = record.parentNode;

            // Deselect children
            function deselectChildren(record) {
                tree.deselect(record.childNodes, false);
                record.eachChild(deselectChildren);
            }
            deselectChildren(record);

            // See if all siblings are selected now
            var allSiblingSelected = false;
            if (parentNode) {
                allSiblingSelected = parentNode.childNodes.reduce(function (previous, node) {
                    return previous && tree.isSelected(node)
                }, true);
            }

            if (allSiblingSelected) {
                tree.select(parentNode, true); // will trigger req 1
            }

            // Deselect ancestors
            else {
                while (parentNode) {
                    tree.deselect(parentNode);
                    parentNode = parentNode.parentNode;
                }
            }
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, no such thing built-in. Oh, now that I think about it, there are those event things that are built into Ext. You can catch one and implement your own logic in there! In your case, that would be the [`select`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.0/#!/api/Ext.panel.Table-event-select) event.

Here's how I suggest to do exactly what you described (using the example tree panel from the doc):

```
Ext.create('Ext.tree.Panel', {
    title: 'Simple Tree',
    renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
    width: 400,
    height: 400,
    store: {
        root: {
            expanded: true,
            children: [
                { text: "detention", leaf: true },
                { text: "homework", expanded: true, children: [
                    { text: "book report", leaf: true },
                    { text: "algebra", expanded: true, children: [
                        { text: "buy lottery tickets", leaf: true }
                    ]}
                ] },
                { text: "buy lottery tickets", leaf: true }
            ]
        }
    },
    rootVisible: false,
    selModel: {
        mode: 'SIMPLE'
    },
    listeners: {
        select: function(tree, record) {
            function deselectChildren(record) {
                tree.deselect(record.childNodes);
                record.eachChild(deselectChildren);
            }
            deselectChildren(record);
        }
    }
});
```

But that gives us a quite weird user experience since you can select the child nodes again, once the parent one has been selected... And to trigger the behaviour (of deselecting child nodes by clicking on their ancestor again), you would have to first deselect the parent, and then reselect it... In a nutshell, IMO, that's confusing.

So, to make all that thing more predictable to the user, I would recommend either deselecting all ancestors when a node is selected by changing the `select` listener this way:

```
select: function(tree, record) {
    // Deselect children
    function deselectChildren(record) {
        tree.deselect(record.childNodes);
        record.eachChild(deselectChildren);
    }
    deselectChildren(record);

    // Deselect ancestors
    var parentNode = record.parentNode;
    while (parentNode) {
        tree.deselect(parentNode);
        parentNode = parentNode.parentNode;
    }
}
```

Or preventing selection of nodes that have an ancestor selected:

```
listeners: {
    select: function(tree, record) {
        function deselectChildren(record) {
            tree.deselect(record.childNodes);
            record.eachChild(deselectChildren);
        }
        deselectChildren(record);
    }
    // Returning false from this event handler will prevent selection (see the doc)
    ,beforeselect: function(tree, record) {
        function isAncestorSelected(record) {
            var parentNode = record.parentNode;
            return tree.isSelected(record) || parentNode && isAncestorSelected(parentNode);
        }
        return !isAncestorSelected(record);
    }
}
```

But, if you want my opinion, that second behaviour is kinda kinky too. I would use the first one.

Now, if you want, you can pack all this in a ux (user extension), publish it in the Sencha market, download it from there, and use it in your code... That way, you'll have your behaviour built into something ;)

**Edit**

Code for requirement 1 + 2 + 3

```
Ext.create('Ext.tree.Panel', {
    title: 'Simple Tree',
    renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
    width: 400,
    height: 400,
    store: {
        root: {
            expanded: true,
            children: [
                { text: "detention", leaf: true },
                { text: "homework", expanded: true, children: [
                    { text: "book report", leaf: true },
                    { text: "algebra", expanded: true, children: [
                        { text: "buy lottery tickets", leaf: true }
                    ]}
                ] },
                { text: "buy lottery tickets", leaf: true }
            ]
        }
    },
    rootVisible: false,
    selModel: {
        mode: 'SIMPLE'
    },
    listeners: {
        select: function(tree, record) {
            var parentNode = record.parentNode;

            // Deselect children
            function deselectChildren(record) {
                tree.deselect(record.childNodes);
                record.eachChild(deselectChildren);
            }
            deselectChildren(record);

            // See if all siblings are selected now
            var allSiblingSelected = false;
            if (parentNode) {
                allSiblingSelected = parentNode.childNodes.reduce(function(previous, node) {
                    return previous && tree.isSelected(node)
                }, true);
            }

            if (allSiblingSelected) {
                // EDIT3: adding true for second argument keepExisting
                tree.select(parentNode, true); // will trigger req 1
            }

            // Deselect ancestors
            else {
                while (parentNode) {
                    tree.deselect(parentNode);
                    parentNode = parentNode.parentNode;
                }
            }
        }
    }
});
```

**Edit 4**

With checkboxes:

```
Ext.create('Ext.tree.Panel', {
    title: 'Simple Tree',
    renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
    width: 400,
    height: 400,
    store: {
        root: {
            expanded: true,
            children: [
                { checked: false, text: "1 detention", expanded: true, children: [
                    {checked: false, text: '1.1 foo', leaf: true},
                    {checked: false, text: '1.2 bar', leaf: true}
                ] },
                { checked: false, text: "2 homework", expanded: true, children: [
                    { checked: false, text: "2.1 book report", leaf: true },
                    { checked: false, text: "2.2 algebra", expanded: true, children: [
                        { checked: false, text: "2.2.1 buy lottery tickets", leaf: true },
                        { checked: false, text: "2.2.2 buy lottery tickets 2", leaf: true }
                    ]}
                ] },
                { checked: false, text: "3 buy lottery tickets", leaf: true }
            ]
        }
    },
    rootVisible: false,
    disableSelection: true,
    //selModel: {mode: 'SIMPLE'},
    listeners: {
        checkchange: function(record, checked, opts) {
            if (!checked) return;
            var parentNode = record.parentNode;

            // Deselect children
            function deselectChildren(record) {
                record.eachChild(function(record) {
                    record.set('checked', false);
                    deselectChildren(record);
                });
            }
            deselectChildren(record);

            // See if all siblings are selected now
            var allSiblingSelected = false;
            if (parentNode) {
                allSiblingSelected = parentNode.childNodes.reduce(function(previous, node) {
                    return previous && node.get('checked');
                }, true);
            }

            if (allSiblingSelected) {
                parentNode.set('checked', true);
                // Apparently won't fire on its own
                this.fireEvent('checkchange', parentNode, true, opts);
            }

            // Deselect ancestors
            else {
                while (parentNode) {
                    parentNode.set('checked', false);
                    parentNode = parentNode.parentNode;
                }
            }
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: I did not ask the entire requirement because that would have made this question really complex. The idea is, 

1) When you selected a node, we need to deselect its entire child’s (direct or indirect).
2) When you select all the child or a node, we need to automatically select its parent & deselect all the child’s.

Comment: And so... Does this answer help you? Do you need help with your second requirement too? And how do you want or plan to handle the problematic case I've exposed? That is, selecting a child node after selecting the parent. You said nothing about that and, if you do nothing, you may end up with both a parent and child node selected at the same time, which is what you want to avoid apparently...

Comment: Honestly, I am still trying to understand the code which you have sent :-). But if you really look at the second requirement, first requirement takes care of it. When all the siblings of a node is selected, all I need to do it select the parent node and the first requirement itself will do the trick for me. Thank you

Comment: Yes, that will do it in that case, but the situation that annoyed me was the following. In you example, if I select node 1.1, nodes 1.1.1, 1.1.2 and 1.1.3 will be deselected, that's the first requirement. But what if now I select node 1.1.2? That doesn't trigger either of your requirement, but we'll then have node 1.1 selected at the same time as its child, node 1.1.2. See?

Comment: When we select a node, we need to see, if all its siblings are selected.if yes, select its parent node (selecting parent will deselect child node). if no, select this node and deselect the parent. I should have explained all these condition but I was worried the question will become confusing and I may not get any replies.

Comment: While its easy to think of handling all these requirement individually, its difficult to implement them all together. They are not mutually exclusive :-(

Comment: Ok, so we agree that we don't want to allow having a parent and child node selected at the same time. I've updated my answer with an example implementing all 3 requirements. That's not too bad, but another funky behaviour emerges when you select a node that has no siblings, that doesn't select this node but it's parent. Might be a bit surprising at first.

Comment: There was a glitch that deselected everything when a parent was selected programatically (see EDIT3 in last code example) but, as far as I've understood your requirements, everything is respected to the letter: http://jsfiddle.net/rixo/BYqRN.

Comment: I just modified your fiddle and added "checked" config in the store model. This property turns the tree panel into CheckBox tree panel. Just by adding this property, the code you shared does not work and that's why there was so much confusion. My tree panel needs to shown as CheckBox tree panel. Please check this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/BYqRN/4/

Comment: Wrong fiddle I suppose, don't see any checkbox in there... Checkbox and selection model are completely dissociated in tree panels though, so I do think my code won't work for that.

Comment: I am not sure how fiddle is working but when I click on the fiddle link I just shared, even I don't see the checkboxes. What I have done now is I have updated the code in my actual question and you can create a fiddle out of it. I can't thank you enough for taking so much time to fix this issue.

Comment: That's not a tremendous modification though... I've updated my answer with code showing checkbox. It's true that the result is less disorienting this way than with the selection model.